# wide parallel bus

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, signal, digital-communications, bus

I need to implement a custom 64-bit wide parallel bus interface operating at 100MHz (800MB/s total bandwidth). While there are no ready solutions for this, is it possible to implement such bus by using two SerDes chips like this: https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/DS92LV3241TVS-NOPB ?

And if yes, can you also suggest which technique should I use to:

1. Couple them together (just use shared clock?);
2. Emulate 100Mhz signal?

Thanks!

---

Thanks everyone guys, I've got the info which helped me to reconsider the system architecture

Comment: Your link doesn't work for me (in the US). Can you link directly to the product page at TI.com?

Comment: What distance do you need to span with your bus?

Comment: I found it [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ds92lv3241.pdf)

Comment: Is this just a unidirectional data bus with a clock, or are there some bi-directional signals?

Comment: @ThePhoton distance is around 30mm

Comment: @crj11 there should be some bi-directional communication, maybe this chip is not the best one. I just try to evaluate the possible solution

Comment: You might be able to use a single 32-bit serdes chip along with a multiplexer to swap the serdes input between the high word and the low word.

Comment: @Felthry but how I will get the 100Mhz speed out of this option?

Comment: Don't ask me--100MHz is a much higher frequency than I've ever worked with!

Comment: For one thing the datasheet for your chip says that the max frequency is 85 MHz, but you say you need 100 MHz.

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't just route the 64 signals directly?  30mm is not that far for 100MHz signals, as long as you have good drivers, termination at the end of the traces, and decent impedance control on the traces.

Comment: @ThePhoton yes, that's why I'm asking can I somehow alter the frequency to get 100MHz...

Comment: @crj11 I was planning to use some serial bus and later expand it to this wide one, thus the need of serdes chips. 64 signals will be almost direct, just need to "pack" the data somehow

Comment: OK, but what crj is suggesting is just route the 64 signals from one place to the other (no serialization required). You haven't given any reason that isn't a good solution to your problem. For the preliminary problem with less traffic, just don't use all the 64 wires.

Comment: A 64-bit 100 MHz bus was the state of art in ordinary 15-years old mainboard designs. There is no technical difficulties other than length matching and maybe some impedance control.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you may be trying to use the SERDES as a PIO Expander, this is not how it is prescribed to be used and you will have a fun time trying to emulate the internal serial link using your host controller.

If you are trying to expand the IO capability of your device to support a physically extant  64 bit parallel bus, you will likely need an external protocol controller with a higher level protocol to your host or application controller, PIO expander chips exist but it will be tough to find ones that will at 100MHZ continuous through put.

Another, less canonical solution is to use a Dual Port RAM (**DPRAM**).

---

The Component you listed DS92LV3241 is intended to be used in a pair with the DS92LV3242

[image]

The intent is to take an existing hardware parallel interface, and stuff it into a reduced signal count serial link in between.

Using this design pattern you can easily make use of 2 pairs of 3242 and 3241 chips to create a serial link between two existing 64 bit bus end points.

This requires the pre-existence of a 64 signals on either end, and precludes the bidirectional channels. For the distances you cite (30mm) you can also just route these two nodes directly.

Comment: It's actually not to hard to drive the LVDS signals directly with an FPGA, but if the original poster is intending to emulate the bus with a micro... that's not going to work very well at all.